# IE Not Displaying CSS, Almost At All

Tags: html, css, wordpress, cross-browser

I have NEVER had this problem before and i am completely stumped.

the site is working fine in everything i've tried (chrome, FF, safari) but is, for lack of a better definition, 'blank' in IE.

html validates with few errors. local css does not validate but errors are ones having to do with webkit/moz border styles, transitions, etc. have deactivated all plugins which does nothing. have taken out all other CSS files and done CSS aggregation, which also does nothing.

screenshot of what it looks like in chrome/FF/safari:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxCtN.png]

screenshot of what it looks like in IE:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXTuJ.png]

any help would be much appreciated.

this is my website where I have the issue:

http://short-stack.net/devel/shoptest/

sincerely,
feeling stupid

Comment: Can you post the url to your site so we can take a look? It's tough to tell with nothing in hand.

Comment: http://short-stack.net/devel/shoptest/

Comment: Weird, i'm getting different results, your site works fine in IE/Chrome for me but not in FF (im running 3.6.23)

Comment: does it look like the 2nd screenshot in FF? i tested in IE9. not in 8 yet. i kind of figured if it was that screwy in 9 then it would definitely be bad in < 8.

Comment: Seems to be working perfectly fine in IE 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found your error, you're missing a quote sign in your style.css sheet in line 159.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "YanoneThin";
    src: url("YanoneKaffeesatz-Thin.ttf(here));
}
```

So your CSS from that point below is not being applied.

Comment: oh my god. i KNEW it had to be something ridiculous. thank you so much. i don't know you but i love you. i'd been looking for missing semicolons for hours now.

Comment: Notepad++ gave it away in a second after i cut and pasted your css.

Comment: i've been using gedit (running fedora). i didn't know notepad++ did that. from now on i shall validate css errors in my windows VM :) thanks again dude.

Comment: You can use Scite under fedora (Notepad++ is based on it). Good luck.

Comment: Apart from Scite, there are several other Linux IDEs with decent syntax highlighting. Coding (even markup) in gedit is not a practical idea. My favorite Linux (web-)IDE would be [Quanta+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quanta_Plus) (needs KDE libraries, though). [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) also is available for Linux. [Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html) also validates CSS. And these three are just a few of the available, off the top of my head.

Comment: Bluefish is very good for web design, i find netbeans to be too heavy for that task but it's also really good.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need an [HTML5 shiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv), such as [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).